# How can I replace all occurrences of a character within matched string in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace all occurrences of a character, say `,`, in a matched string in `sed`. The matched string looks like:

```
[cite!abc,cde]
```

I want to replace it with:

```
[!cite](abc, cde)
```

The command to replace the outer format is:

```
sed 's/\[cite\!\([^]]+\)\]/\[\!cite\]\(\1\)/g' file
```

which gives

```
[!cite](abc,cde)
```

However, I want to put space after `,` and there may be an arbitrary number or comma delimited entries, e.g.

```
[cite!abc,cde,def,fgh]
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this in `sed` or do I need to resort to perl scripts?

Answer (score 1):

If you're guaranteed no spaces after commas in the input string:

```
sed 's/,/, /g' file
```

If you do have spaces after the commas in the input string, you'll get extra spaces in the output.

EDIT:

If there may be spaces after the commas in some of the elements, you can avoid adding more with:

```
sed 's/,\([^ ]\)/, \1/g' file
```

```
$ echo '1, 2, 3,4,5,6' | sed -e 's/,\([^ ]\)/, \1/g'
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: This works, but I do not want to disturb text outside the matched space as it has other markup that can contain ',' in a string.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;/\[([^]!]+)!([^]]+)\]/{s//\n[!\1](\2)\n/;h;s/,/, /g;H;g;s/\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/;ta}' file
```

The solution comes in two parts:

1. The string to be amended are identified, and a first pass rearranges to the requires format less the comma space separated list.
2. The string is surrounded by newlines and a copy is made into the hold space. Then the current pattern space is has all commas space separated and the copy and current line are joined and using patten matching formatted to final required state.

The process is then repeated on the current line so as to effect a global replacement.

Comment: That is some strong Kung Fu! Still trying to figure out H;g;.